# indexedDB over multiple machines

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, indexeddb

I am currently working on an interaction event tracker for websites. One feature I am looking at adding is the capability to store specific values of elements on the pages and store them in the browser with indexedDb API.

As an extension, I would love to implement a cross-browser implementation so that I can carry the values with me across multiple machines (I use chrome on mac, personal and business machines). I know there are limitations to what indexedDB can do but isn't there a way to carry the indexedDB database between browsers till I am logged into the same account in Chrome?

Any help or direction will be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone got a chance to look into this but I found out that "storage" API allows you to do what I want, i.e, store data that sync over the cloud

`User data can be automatically synced with Chrome sync (using storage.sync). Your extension's content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.`

I hope this helps anyone who goes down this path
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/